# Disable constant user authentication

Tags: password, authentication

I've been using windows for 10 years, and now discovered Ubuntu, which is way cooler, but the downside is that I'm at a complete lost.. So far , so good but what I find annoying is that I have to type my password for every single thing I do, is there a way to disable that?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: When you first get Ubuntu it can feel like this, especially because you're constantly installing/updating, relogging, restarting. But after you get to the point where you're just using it as your everyday machine this sensation passes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use a password for every single thing you do then I would suspect that you have a problem.

If though you mean you have to supply a password when doing things that impact on the system files then this is good.

Just because you had windows set up to run without something as basic as a password doesn't mean you should transfer the behaviour ;)

If you find that you are running a lot of commands in one go try

```
sudo -i
```

Run the commands and then exit.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo